# Image scale from center of display using matrix

Tags: android-imageview

every one.
I'm a android developer.
I want to scale my image from center of displayed part of image with matrix.
So, I scaled my image with matrix. And then moved it with the calculated pointer.
But, the Application not work correctly.
This can't find the correct center, so when it does, it moved right.
Why this is?
I can't find the problem.

The code followed.

```
            matrix.reset();
            curScale += 0.02f;
            orgImage.getHeight();
            w = orgImage.getWidth();
            matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
            rtnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(orgImage, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, true);
            curImageView.setImageBitmap(rtnBitmap);
            Matrix curZoomOutMatrix = new Matrix();

            pointerx =(int ) ((mDisplayWidth/2 - curPosX) * curScale);
            curPosX = - pointerx;
            pointery =(int ) ((mDisplayWidth/2 - curPosY) * curScale);
            curPosY =  - pointery;

            Log.i("ZoomOut-> posX = ", Integer.toString(curPosX));
            Log.i("ZoomOut-> posY = ", Integer.toString(curPosY));
            curZoomOutMatrix.postTranslate(curPosX, curPosY);
            curImageView.setImageMatrix(curZoomOutMatrix);
            curImageView.invalidate();
```

Did you have any sample code for center zoomIn and zoomOut the imageView with matrix?
Who can explain for that?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, It's my fault.
First, I scale the image from original one.
So, The image is (width, height) * scale;
Then I calculate the absolute position of the point that is displayed center. And then, move my ImageView to the calculated position from which the view is. My fault are here.
When i calculate view position, I change the position from now scale.
So, when it scaled, the position is not `<original position> * <now scale>`. It was `<original position * <scale> * <now scale>`, the result was strange position.
So i remade add to calculate the center position from original one.

That mode is now following.

```
public void calculate(float offset) {

    float tmpScale = curScale - offset;
    float orgWidth = (mDisplayWidth / 2 - curPosX) / tmpScale;
    float orgHeight = (mDisplayHeight / 2 - curPosY) / tmpScale;
    int tmpPosX = (int)(mDisplayWidth / 2 - orgWidth * curScale);
    int tmpPosY = (int)(mDisplayHeight / 2 - orgHeight * curScale);

    curPosX = tmpPosX;
    curPosY = tmpPosY;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postTranslate(tmpPosX, tmpPosY);

    curImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    curImageView.invalidate();
}
```

Thank you. every one.